# How do I present lots of options, few of which are required?

Tags: ipad, options, dialog

I have a flow in an iPad app that takes the user through the process of creating a fairly complex object. For the sake of simplicity, lets say they are scheduling a meeting. There are actually a lot of options you can choose from when creating the meeting but only a few of them are required. The basic idea is to allow the user to get a meeting up and running very quickly by presenting them with a small set of required fields but also letting them specify other helpful options if they wish.

The current design makes use of a semi-wizard control where the first page contains all the required data that has to be there to create the meeting. The subsequent pages contain the optional items. So it appears kind of like a wizard to the user but it's more of a set of tabs since you don't have to complete one page to get to the next.

Anyway, it's fairly clunky. It comes off as a bit overwhelming (there are 4 pages to the "wizard"). I'm struggling a bit with how to make it clear to the user that they only have to fill in the first page to actually get their meeting while still encouraging them to at least consider some of the other options since they will make using the app easier. Also, filling in a lot of data on an iPad isn't always a great experience, especially when a lot of typing is involved.

I realize it's hard to give suggestions when you don't know much about the app itself, but does anyone have any example apps that solve this problem well?

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following flow. Hub page contains appropriate links which allow to set additional parameters.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dissect your wizard: Present the hypothetical **Create meeting** button after the minimal requirements are fulfilled, then either:

- Hide the other options behind a **settings** button (with a gear or tool icon).

or

- **Prompt** the user to fill in the additional options after "landing" on his newly created appointment, but make sure to allow him to ignore this. Something like:

[image]

(I know, it's an iPhone, but you get the point)